# Adjusting the 'date' command to subtract three hours

Tags: date

In a bash script, I have the following 3 lines:

```bsh
D=`date -u +%Y%m%d`
H=`date -u +%H`
RUNTIME="${D}_${H}00"
```

I need to have the `RUNTIME` adjusted to 3 hours earlier than the current time. So this would mainly involve editing `H`, but also `D` since the day could shift back during the first couple hours of the current day. How can I modify all this to subtract the 3 hours? Thanks.

Comment: What version of `date` are you using?

Comment: Not sure about the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `date` from `coreutils` you can do this:

```bsh
D=`date -u '+%Y%m%d' -d '-3 hours'`
H=`date -u '+%H' -d '-3 hours'`
RUNTIME="${D}_${H}00"
```

The `-d` option lets you specify a date other than now, it supports the addition/substraction of hours, days, etc.

Also, do you need `D` and `H` other than to create `RUNTIME`?  If not, you could just do:

```bsh
RUNTIME=`date -u '+%Y%m%d_%H00' -d '-3 hours'`
```